# Calling a PHP variable in a IF statement?

Tags: php, mybb

I am working with MyBB and I am a beginner PHP user. I am trying to display some CSS code depending on if a variable is 0 or higher. My PHP code is as follows.

```
<?php

if({$GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice']} > 0){

   echo '<style type="text/css">
    p.price {
        display:inline; 
        padding:3px; 
        border-radius:7px; 
        background:#66CD00;}
    </style>';

} else {
   echo '<style type="text/css">
    p.price {
        display: none;}
    </style>';
}
?>
```

I am working with something called xThreads so it gives me custom fields for certain forums. I am able to call that variable just by using

```
{$GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice']}
```

If I were to echo it I could by doing:

```
<?php
echo "{$GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice']}";
?>
```

That above works, however when I try to run it in the IF statement it gives me a error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'
```

On this line

```
if({$GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice']} > 0){
```

I was able to figure it out.

```
<?php

if( $GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice'] > 0){
    echo "<p style=\"display:inline; border-radius:7px; background:#66CD00; padding:3px;\">{$GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice']}</p>";

}
?>
```

I put that inline where it should display and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if({$GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice']} > 0){
```

to this:

```
if($GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice'] > 0){
```

**Additional braces should not be present in if statements hence the error you are getting:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'
```

Comment: That fixed the error, however my CSS is not taking affect.

Comment: @user3858124 Hmm that means your variable has a value you were not expecting. Please do `var_dump($GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice'])` to see if it holds the value you are expecting.

Comment: string(0) "" string(0) "" string(5) "54.00" string(5) "34.00" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "". When I have ran the echo to that variable it gave me the 54.00 and 34.00. (Only 2 of these threads have price input into them which is why the others are blank.

Comment: @user3858124 These are multiple values.Did it print them in one var_dump() or did you run the code several times?

Comment: I only ran it once. It is in a template that gets called multiple times I assume. This template is ran for each "thread" in the forum. I have 7 threads right now.

Comment: @user3858124 If the template is ran multiple times then both conditions will be taken since you have sometimes a 0 value and sometimes a positive value. Thus both CSS rules will be sent. And the last one will win here the `display: none` one. This is why your code does not work.

Comment: Oh, so this isn't possible?

Comment: @user3858124 Well everything is possible but this is not the right way. I assume there is a way to differentiate the price fields as the template is ran multiple times. Please be more specific in what is your problem. Don't hesitate to post links. The more precise you are the better I'll be able to help you.

Comment: Well I don't really have any links to show. But Basically this page here: http://codegamer.net/forumdisplay.php?fid=3&filtertf_trdftnt[]=Buy&filtertf_trdftnt[]=Sell next to the subject of each thread should display the price. It will be a formatted box with green background. If the thread does not have a price, i don't want to display the box. So I wanted to check if the price was less than 0 and then change the CSS to none basically.

Comment: Ok I get it now :) I just have a few more questions, where should be the p.price elements. Because I dont see any. Even in the source code of this webpage

Comment: I am actually trying a bunch of new things right now. I removed the class and was just trying to run the PHP inline. I wish there was another place we could talk, Skype? Anyways, I had the p.price in the PHP if statement so if the price was greater than 0 it would then display css properties for p.price. If it wasn't greater then p.price would just display nothing.

Comment: AH I got it figured out! 
    <?php

if( $GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice'] > 0){
echo "<p style=\"display:inline; border-radius:7px; background:#66CD00; padding:3px;\">{$GLOBALS['threadfields']['trdfprice']}</p>";

}
?>

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad for you then :)

Comment: Then it was more a CSS question than a PHP question, but you can still mark my answer as accepted if this helped you :)